# Can the compositor be used to batch process images?

Tags: scripting, compositing-nodes

There are tools to batch process images already of course, (such as **ImageMagick**), but this isn't as flexible as Blender's compositor since they typically perform linear operations and don't have the control you get with a node-tree.

Is there some way to take point Blender at a directory of images (for example), and batch process them (using an existing compositor setup).

Answer (score 10):

Yes, one not so elegant (no scripting :) but easy way to go about this would be to just use the *Movie Clip* node and point it to the directory with the images, pass it as input to your node group/compositor setup and render it out as an animation of stills or output each separately using the *File Output* node.

The only con or drawback to this approach is that the images need to be in a sequence for Blender to iterate through them.. `img_001, img_002 ... img_00n` or so you can scrub through in the clip editor or timeline but otherwise it should work as desired.

Answer (score 10):

You could setup a blend file with the composite nodes setup as desired, ensuring you start from an image input node and finish with a composite node, then script setting the input and output image names.

[image]

```
import bpy, os

# configure input and oupt dirs 
inputDir = '/tmp/input'
outputDir = '/tmp/output'
# ensure this points to the input image node - name can vary
inputNode = bpy.context.scene.node_tree.nodes['Image']

inputImages = os.listdir(inputDir)
bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_percentage = 100

for i in inputImages:
    inputNode.image.filepath = os.path.join(inputDir,i)
    bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_x = inputNode.image.size[0]
    bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_y = inputNode.image.size[1]
    bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = os.path.join(outputDir,i)
    bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)
```

Answer (score 5):

I have just written a script to batch process images from the compositor.

Example use:

```
batch_compo.py --blend=compo.blend --input="./img_src/*.png" --output="./img_dst"
```

Its a single script, but linking to the repository which includes a readme.

See: https://gitlab.com/ideasman42/batch-compo