# Single Image rendering with blender netrender

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes, network

I read this post ([Is netrender only useful for multiple frames?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2002/6433)) about rendering a single image with netrender.
But how can I combine those images very quickly and easily? Say for example I have 100 single images.  How would I do this?

Thanks

Comment: The easiest way would probably be by using [image magick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) or some other batch editing tool. If you want to do it in blender, you could try something like [this](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5017/599) or [this](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/15755/599)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Something other.. would it be possible when i write a java program, that it uses the average pixel colors to make a combined image? Or is this different than doing it with blender or image magick?