# Is netrender still only useful for multiple frames?

Tags: rendering, network

I saw [this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2002/is-netrender-only-useful-for-multiple-frames) from 2013 and [this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16682/single-image-rendering-with-blender-netrender) stating that the NetRender plugin does not yet have the ability to render single frames properly. Is this still true, or is the functionality just hidden away or in beta?

Comment: AFAIK there isn't anyone actively adding features to it. [Many of the files haven't been touched since 2012 or earlier](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/BA/browse/master/netrender/).

Comment: recently I see this post on BN but I don't know if it fits your needs...
http://www.blendernation.com/2015/09/07/distributed-single-frame-render-for-blender-cycles/

Comment: @m.ardito Incredibly useful! Thanks for showing me this, I'll totally try it out.